# I2C stops working if a DiBcom DVB USB adapter is plugged

Tags: raspbian, i2c

I can't help to get my I2C device (an Adafruit Pi Plate I just bought and built) to work in my Raspbian machine. Although the command `sudo modprobe i2c-bcm2708` showed no errors, something strange appears in `dmesg`:

```
[  275.580368] bcm2708_i2c_init_pinmode(0,0)
[  275.580401] bcm2708_i2c_init_pinmode(0,1)
[  275.580490] bcm2708_i2c bcm2708_i2c.0: could not add I2C adapter: -16
[  275.580551] bcm2708_i2c: probe of bcm2708_i2c.0 failed with error -16
[  275.580607] bcm2708_i2c_init_pinmode(1,2)
[  275.580622] bcm2708_i2c_init_pinmode(1,3)
[  275.580686] bcm2708_i2c bcm2708_i2c.1: could not add I2C adapter: -16
[  275.580732] bcm2708_i2c: probe of bcm2708_i2c.1 failed with error -16
```

After a lot of research, I've found that the loading fails if my DVB adapter, an Asus My Cinema U3000 Mini, is plugged in. If I unplug it, dmesg shows

```
[   12.331518] bcm2708_i2c_init_pinmode(0,0)
[   12.337053] bcm2708_i2c_init_pinmode(0,1)
[   12.345332] bcm2708_i2c bcm2708_i2c.0: BSC0 Controller at 0x20205000 (irq 79) (baudrate 100000)
[   12.357036] bcm2708_i2c_init_pinmode(1,2)
[   12.369518] bcm2708_i2c_init_pinmode(1,3)
[   12.379588] bcm2708_i2c bcm2708_i2c.1: BSC1 Controller at 0x20804000 (irq 79) (baudrate 100000)
```

and the example program runs flawlessly.

The same happens if I add `i2c-bcm2708` and `i2c-dev` in /etc/modules. So it looks like the load order is not important.

How can I get both the I2C bus and the DVB adapter work on the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The i2c-bcm2708 is blacklisted by default in Raspbian.

Remove or comment out the `blacklist i2c-bcm2708` line in `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`, and keep loading i2c-bcm2708 in /etc/modules. This way, i2c-bcm2708 is loaded before any other USB device, including the Asus U3000.